# Shader about Skeleton Animation in AGAL

Tags: agal

In my project, we push a part of the matrix to constant registers for skeleton animation and access them with matrix index in shader which also passed by constant registers.

a sample shader with glsles:

```
uniform highp vec4 mPalette[60];             //a part of the matrix for skeleton.
attribute highp vec4 _glesVertex;               //the input positions.
attribute vec4 mBlendindices;      //the matrix index.
void main ()
{
    gl_Position = mPalette[mBlendindices.x];
}
```

If I assign the value "mPalette" to use constant registers: vc0 - vc59, assign the value "mBlendindices" to use constant registers: vc60, assign _glesVertex to use vertex attribute registers: va0.

how to translate this shader to AGAL?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutelly the same. You should pass all your constants and attributes to shaders (I assume you know how to pass it in actionscript). Next, in vertex shader:

```
mov op, vc[va.x]
```